# initialRouteName is not working on the loading screen I want to set

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have have a bottom tab navigation in my react native application. Inside of the bottom tab navigation I have tab navigation that is nested. Something the navigation setup I have is causing my react native application to crash in Test Flight when I test it through apple developer. I know there is something wrong with the navigation but i can not figure it out. I thought it was the `initialRouteName` but I am not sure. Would anyone be able to look at my navigation file and see if there is anything wrong with it from looking at it.

The app crashes during the build in test flight but runs perfectly when I test it on my local development testing and local phone.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

import ContactAgentScreen from './src/screens/ContactAgentScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from './src/screens/FavoritesScreen';
import FeedScreen from './src/screens/FeedScreen';
import GalleryScreen from './src/screens/GalleryScreen';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
import PropertyScreen from './src/screens/PropertyScreen';
import SellHomeScreen from './src/screens/SellHomeScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import FilterScreen from './src/screens/FilterScreen'
import RecentViewScreen from './src/screens/RecentViewScreen'
import OfferInformationScreen from './src/screens/OfferInformationScreen'
import OfferScreen from './src/screens/OfferScreen'
import PaymentCalculationScreen from './src/screens/PaymentCalculationScreen'
import ThankYouScreen from './src/screens/ThankYouScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './src/screens/SettingsScreen'
import AboutUsScreen from './src/screens/AboutUsScreen'
import ResetPassword from './src/screens/ResetPassword'
import PasswordResetConfirmationScreen from './src/screens/PasswordResetConfirmationScreen'
import FullMapScreen from './src/screens/FullMapScreen'
import InvestmentScreen from './src/screens/InvestmentScreen'

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator();
const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={MainScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ContactAgentWithStack" component={ContactAgentScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="GallerStack" component={GalleryScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="FilterStack" component={FilterScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="OfferInformationScreen" component={OfferInformationScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="FullMapScreen" component={FullMapScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginStackScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const FeedStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Feed' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FeedScreen" component={FeedScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyFeedScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginFeedScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const FavoriteStack = () => {
  return (
    //headerShown: false
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Favorite' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoritesScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyFavoriteScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginFavoriteScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const InvestmentStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Profile' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="InvestmentScreen" component={InvestmentScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyInvestmentScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const ProfStackile = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Profile' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="RecentViewScreen" component={RecentViewScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="ContactAgentScreen" component={ContactAgentScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SellHomeScreen" component={SellHomeScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SignupScreen" component={SignupScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="OfferScreen" component={OfferScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="PaymentCalculatorScreen" component={PaymentCalculationScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ThankYouScreen" component={ThankYouScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="AboutUsScreen" component={AboutUsScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ResetPasswordScreen" component={ResetPassword} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="PasswordResetConfirmationScreen" component={PasswordResetConfirmationScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="#61dafb"
        barStyle={{color: 'black'}}/>
      <TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Home' 
          name="Home" 
          component={HomeStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"home"} color={color} size={size} />),
          }}/> 
        {/* <TabNav.Screen key='Recommended' name="Recommended" component={RecommendedStack} /> */}
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Favorites' 
          name="Favorites" 
          component={FavoriteStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"heart"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Feed' 
          name="Feed" 
          component={FeedStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"menu"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Propertyies' 
          name="Properties" 
          component={InvestmentStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"trending-up"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        {/* <TabNav.Screen key='Messages' name="Messages" component={MessagesStack} />  */}
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Profile' 
          name="Profile" 
          component={ProfStackile} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"user"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
      </TabNav.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default App;
```

----UPDATED VERSION--------

app.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

import ContactAgentScreen from './src/screens/ContactAgentScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from './src/screens/FavoritesScreen';
import FeedScreen from './src/screens/FeedScreen';
import GalleryScreen from './src/screens/GalleryScreen';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
import PropertyScreen from './src/screens/PropertyScreen';
import SellHomeScreen from './src/screens/SellHomeScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import FilterScreen from './src/screens/FilterScreen'
import RecentViewScreen from './src/screens/RecentViewScreen'
import OfferInformationScreen from './src/screens/OfferInformationScreen'
import OfferScreen from './src/screens/OfferScreen'
import PaymentCalculationScreen from './src/screens/PaymentCalculationScreen'
import ThankYouScreen from './src/screens/ThankYouScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './src/screens/SettingsScreen'
import AboutUsScreen from './src/screens/AboutUsScreen'
import ResetPassword from './src/screens/ResetPassword'
import PasswordResetConfirmationScreen from './src/screens/PasswordResetConfirmationScreen'
import FullMapScreen from './src/screens/FullMapScreen'
import InvestmentScreen from './src/screens/InvestmentScreen'

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator();
const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='HomeScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={MainScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ContactAgentWithStack" component={ContactAgentScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="GallerStack" component={GalleryScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="FilterStack" component={FilterScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="OfferInformationScreen" component={OfferInformationScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="FullMapScreen" component={FullMapScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginStackScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const FeedStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='FeedScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FeedScreen" component={FeedScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyFeedScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginFeedScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const FavoriteStack = () => {
  return (
    //headerShown: false
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='FavoriteScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoritesScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyFavoriteScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginFavoriteScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const InvestmentStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='InvestmentScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="InvestmentScreen" component={InvestmentScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyInvestmentScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const ProfStackile = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='ProfileScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="RecentViewScreen" component={RecentViewScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="ContactAgentScreen" component={ContactAgentScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SellHomeScreen" component={SellHomeScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SignupScreen" component={SignupScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="OfferScreen" component={OfferScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="PaymentCalculatorScreen" component={PaymentCalculationScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ThankYouScreen" component={ThankYouScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="AboutUsScreen" component={AboutUsScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ResetPasswordScreen" component={ResetPassword} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="PasswordResetConfirmationScreen" component={PasswordResetConfirmationScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="#61dafb"
        barStyle={{color: 'black'}}/>
      <TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='HomeScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Home' 
          name="Home" 
          component={HomeStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"home"} color={color} size={size} />),
          }}/> 
        {/* <TabNav.Screen key='Recommended' name="Recommended" component={RecommendedStack} /> */}
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Favorites' 
          name="Favorites" 
          component={FavoriteStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"heart"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Feed' 
          name="Feed" 
          component={FeedStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"menu"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Propertyies' 
          name="Properties" 
          component={InvestmentStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"trending-up"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        {/* <TabNav.Screen key='Messages' name="Messages" component={MessagesStack} />  */}
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Profile' 
          name="Profile" 
          component={ProfStackile} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"user"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
      </TabNav.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are `initiaRouteName` are not correct. For example in `<StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Feed'` there is no route with name `Feed` but there exit `FeedScreen`. So you may like to add the correct name.
Validate same for other routes also

Another error here

```
<StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Profile' screenOptions= {{headerShown: false}}>
       <StackNav.Screen name="InvestmentScreen" component={InvestmentScreen}/>
       <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyInvestmentScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
</StackNav.Navigator>
```

There is no screen with name `Profile` here.

Comment: I fixed all of the naming issues. So the ```initialRouteName``` in the TabNav that has nested stack navigation should look like this ... ```<TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='HomeScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>```?? I also added an updated version of the app.js file in the question as a reference.